# Swift firebase querydata by string array

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to filter data by a string array within firebase to return only the filtered values but the app crashes when I try to run the function. Is this the way it should be done? (The function isn't called if the array is empty)

```
    func fetchFilteredActivities() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "category").queryEqual(toValue: filterList)
    ref.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        guard let uid = dictionary["uid"] as? String else { return }

        guard let latitudeString = dictionary["latitude"] as? String else { return }
        guard let longitudeString = dictionary["longitude"] as? String else { return }

        let latitude = (latitudeString as NSString).doubleValue
        let longitude = (longitudeString as NSString).doubleValue

        Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: uid, completion: { (user) in
            guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            var post = Post(postId: snapshot.key, user: user, dictionary: dictionary)

            let postId = snapshot.key
            post.id = snapshot.key

            let coords = [CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)]
            self.addAnnotation(post: post, title: post.category, subtitle: nil, coords: coords)
        })
    }
}
```

**The error:**
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: "the app crashes when I try to run the function" What are the exact error message and stack trace?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen added the error to my question

Comment: What @FrankvanPuffelen was asking was: What *line* is it crashing on and what is the specific error. also, including your structure is very helpful (as text please, no images)

Comment: Also, remember that we don't know the scope of your app, so things like `filterList` are a mystery to us. What is a `filterList`? This `Database.fetchUserWithUID(` doesn't look like a good idea either. What's the backing code?